# UISearchController.searchBar not responding on tap

Tags: swift3

Search bar not respond to tap/click?

First create UITableView in UIView

[image]

then add search bar in table header

[image]

and Cancel button respond, but search label not.

Conf method:

```
func configureSearchController() {

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
```

and call from here:

```
let dimension = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: Int(dialogContainer.layer.frame.width), height: Int(dialogContainer.layer.frame.height - 100))
self.tableView = UITableView(frame: dimension, style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DropdownCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DropdownCell")
self.tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none

configureSearchController() // <-

dialogContainer.addSubview(tableView)
self.tableView.reloadData()
```